# Android: Toolbar Text color

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm trying to use a theme in my Toolbar. I want to change the text color but I can't do it, and I don't know why. The text color is not being applied, instead of be brown it appears me with black color. Can you please help me?

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <!-- Set proper title size -->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/brown</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_main"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title">    
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="brown" type="color">#b78c07</item>

    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/brown</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: why dont you do it  programmatically? check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269471/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-the-text-of-my-actionbar-its-not-working/28269538#28269538)

Comment: @Elltz Thanksss it worked! Please answer for I can accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set the `Toolbar` title color programmatically

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
ToolBar.setTitleTextColor(Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)));
```

This sets a random color, at runtime, you can add your preferred colour.
`Color.RED`,`Color.BLUE` etc.

THanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/MyToolbar" />


<style name="MyToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <!-- android:textColorPrimary is the  color of the title text
     in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

  <!-- android:textColorPrimaryInverse is the  color of the title
       text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme:  -->
 <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```