# Change text color in toolbar / action bar, android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to change the text color and the navigation icon color in the toolbar

[image]

Change the text color of the action item "13311"

And also of the drawer icon.

The styles
    //activity theme

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <item name="switchStyle">@style/Switch</item>
</style>


//theme for switch widget
<style name="Switch" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_selector</item>
    <item name="showText">false</item>
</style>

//toolbar theme
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <!--<item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>-->
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

//overflow menu theme
<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>

//action button theme
<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Did you try toolbar light theme, I think you are using dark style for your toolbar that's why menu items shows in black

Comment: Which is the light theme for toolbar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Toolbar Text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888852/android-toolbar-text-color)

Comment: @Elltz How is it duplicate? There is no solution in your link as to which solves my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- text color for action menu icons -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    <!-- overflow menu icon color -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

**Edit**
To change the navigation drawer color use

```
<style name="DrawerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/drawer_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the parent theme to darkactionbar
when the action bar is dark you will get your icon and text white , when it is light you will get them black .
that's all

```
  <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: sorry about that , i tried to comment , not to answer , this stack exchange app doesn't allow to delete answer

Answer (score 0):

To change arrow color I used **colorControlNormal**
from **AppTheme** and **AppTheme.ActionBarTheme**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <!-- Toolbar Theme / Apply white arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTextAppearance</item>

    <!-- Material Theme -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/statusBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- White arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/drawerArrowColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What about the action text?? "1331"

Comment: For the action text color
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>`